# Order of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the order of the following elements:
(1)7 in U8 (I think it is 8)

(2) ((Top row) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 Bottom Row 2 3 7 5 1 4 6) in S7 (I got 5)

(3)Also, is there any easy way to find the order of a matrix except multiplying them till you  get the identity!

(U8, here is group whose elements are relatively prime to 8)

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is U8 and S7? Also, you can use $\$ $\pmatrix{1&2&..&7\\2&3&7..}$\$ $

Comment: Aha, U8 is now clear, we rather denote it something like $\Bbb Z_8^\times$, because these elements (the coprimes) form a group under *multiplication*, and not addition. In particular, it has less elements than $8$ (how many and which ones?) S7 is still not clear. Contains which matrices? And what are the other rows?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, Berci! U8= {1,3,5,7} 
S7 is the symmetric group with the defined permutation
Matrix will be something like ((Top Row)0 1 (Bottom Row) b c) where b, c are are Reals)

Comment: Ah, *permutation*, not matrix. Ok. $S_7$ is standard. And what's the next guess for the order of $7$ among $\{1,3,5,7\}$ w.r.t. multiplication, modulo $8$?

Comment: It's easier to find the order of (2) if you write your permutation as a product of disjoint cycles, like $(1\; 2\; 3\; 7\; 6\; 4\; 5)$

Comment: Both what you got in (1)-(2) is wrong. Berci's hints can help you now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. $7\equiv -1\pmod{8}$
2. Write this permutation $\sigma:=\pmatrix{ 1 &2 &3 &4& 5& 6& 7\\ 2 &3& 7& 5& 1& 4 &6}$ as a composition of disjoint cycles, then the order will be the lowest common multiplier of the cycle lengths. You can start by
   $$1\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto...$$
   then either you will use up all 7 elements (that means 1 cycle of length $7$), or you have more cycles.